# What are the various map randomisations for the Charlie Santa heist?

Tags: payday-2

The first annual Christmas heist for Payday 2 has been released - codenamed "Charlie Santa". It takes place at the Go Bank and the objective is to steal the contents of the vault... or the vault, depending on how you approach the mission.

[image]

What are the various map randomisations for the Charlie Santa heist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In comparison to the other [Bank Heist level](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/131676/52800) used in the Bank Heist: Cash/Deposit Boxes/Gold heists and on Firestarter Day 3, the Go Bank has a minimal number of randomisations. The actual physical layout of the building doesn't change, however there are a variety of civilian, guards, and [keycard spawn points](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/146518/52800;).

The map consists of seven main areas;

- The front of the bank
- The store to the left of the bank
- The car workshop to the right of the bank
- The back of the bank
- The main lobby of the bank
- The corridor along the back of the bank
- The roof of the bank

It is possible that a GenSec armoured transport will be present in front of the bank at the start of the heist which will have an additional two guards sat in the front of the transport (which will require pager answers if killed) and some additional loot in the back of the transport.

[image]

There is a possibility for workers (general civilians in work uniforms) to spawn in various locations around the bank, the car workshop, and the store next to the bank. There are a minimal number of civilians walking around on the street, this seems to be two or one with a stationary civilian stood next to the benches outside the front of the bank;

[image]

The position of the cars in the front and the back of the bank do not seem to move, however most of them has the chance to spawn a keycard inside it and you will need two keycards if you wish to stealth this level. It is relatively easy to mask up at the start of the heist and work your way through the cars, through the buildings to the left and right of the bank, around to the back of the bank.

[image]

Inside the bank you will find between guards, civilians, a bank manager and an assistant bank manager/senior clerk. You will also find cameras. The cameras will either be in the back corridor running along the back of the bank, or in the main lobby area of the bank (or both). The bank is relatively open plan and the vault is in the lobby so you're going to need some crowd control regardless.

It is possible that the vault will be open as part of the spawn, and further possible that the manager and possibly guards will be inside the open vault.

[image]

You will need cable ties to take care of the civilians, or cleaner to get rid of the bodies. Additionally, there are a large number of randomised events that can occur both while stealthing the heist or while doing it loud, including;

- GenSec phone calls which will result in sending over GenSec guards, and later, police
- GenSec calling for a confirmation code, which can be found behind the clerks' desk
- Getting black mailed by some guy for a share of the loot when you throw it over the wall during your escape
- A combination of motion sensors and cameras in the vault itself